# Getting a string value from flask using angular

Tags: angular, flask, observable

I know that there are a lot of tutorials available which show how to connect to flask via angular. However, I am not successful with displaying a simple string fetched from flask and ask you kindly to have a look at my code. What I can tell is that I can start the Flask server and I am also able to see the string in the browser, if I directly connect to the Flask port. The problems start with angular.

Here is the short Flask code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def fetch_acceleration_data():
    return "hallo"
```

The server runs on port 5000 on the local host. In angular, I have this service:

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, tap} from 'rxjs';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment.prod';
import { ACC } from './flaskcon';

@Injectable()
export class testService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getAcc(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(environment.apiURL);
      }
}
```

getAcc is meant to get the string value. The environment is specified like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
};
```

In my app component, I have the method gnOnInit:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { ACC } from './flaskcon';
import { testService } from './flaskcon.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  title = 'test';
  accListSubs: Subscription;
  accList: string;

  constructor(private accAPI: testService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = 'anders'
    this.accListSubs = this.accAPI
      .getAcc().subscribe((res:any) => {
        this.accList = res;
      }
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.accListSubs.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

As I understand it, accList should store the string from flask. But "res" ist always undefined. Interestingly, there is a http request shown in the flask server log, which indicates a successful get request with code 200.

I am sorry for the variable names. Later, I want to transfer acceleration values from a database. As I got these problems, I first tried to transfer a simple string.

Comment: did you check the network tab for the browser when making that HTTP call? can you confirm if the response is `undefined`?

Comment: I deleted my previous comment where I said that the network section does not display anything. I looked at the wrong place. The browser network tab shows the connection to the flask server and also confirms with 200.

Comment: and what was the response in the network tab? was it indeed `undefined`?

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want to know, but the type in the developer tools says "xhr", which sounds correct to me. I have the feeling that there is something wrong with the usage of the subscribe method, because the variable accList is never initialized.

Comment: You can check what the response is when you make an http call in the network tab, you can see the payload you send and the response from the backend, you should be able to see what the response is since you are getting 200... the logic in the angular code looks fine. Also, you could try running Postman or Insomia, make a GET call to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` and see what the response is... if it is empty, undefined, then the endpoint is sending that...

Comment: Andres, this was a useful hint. After looking a little bit more closely at the developer tools console, I saw that an error message was returned (still marked with 200 though). The error message said that there was a parsing error, which probably existed because a json was expected. I do not know. However, adding {responseType: 'text} to the http-get request solved the problem.